# Emitting Object from Parent to Child

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS. I have two components. The first one is a parent to the second one. The parent has an array saving object whereas we get the objects by listening to the child.

**Child**

```
<template>
  <div>
    Create a new item <button @click="createItem">Create Item</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      item: {
        id: null
      },
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createItem () {
      this.item.id = this.count
      this.count = this.count + 1
      this.$emit('setItem', this.item)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Parent**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child @setItem="addItem"></child>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id">
        {{ item.id }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './Child.vue'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem (item) {
      this.items.push(item)
    }
  },
  components: {
    child: Child
  }
}
</script>
```

So you have a button. If you click on the button, you set the item property of the child. You then emit this item. You get it in the parent, add that object to the array and render it.

Expected behavior: On each click, the list grows by one item whereas each new item is one bigger than the last. Resulting in a list of increasing numbers.

Actual behavior: The list grows with each click by one. That's fine. But all items are updated to the biggest/newest number.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-architecture-85b7d?file=/src/App.vue

Now, I know I could just pass a number instead of an object but keep in mind, that this is just a minimal reproduction. My actual object looks like this: (if it matters)

```
measurement: {
  id: null,
  start: 0,
  pauses: [],
  stop: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the same item every time.

The parent holds a reference to the child's item. There is only one, so when you updated it you update all elements in the parent's array, as they reference the same object.

You have 2 ways of dealing with this.

Either do a clone in the child or in the parent.

In the child this should work:

```
this.$emit('setItem', Object.assign({}, this.item))
```

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-engelbart-y8zb2)

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought and I tried to create a new object each time with Object.create() etc but it didn't work. I think I'll be able to solve it now. So just to clarify: $emit actually passes the reference, thus the behavior where each item get's updated to the last set vale? Where do I look up how emit exactly works? the APiI reference of VueJS somehow doesn't talk about how it exactly passes. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you'll find this distinction in the emit docs. This is standard JS behaviour for passing arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I'll research that then - seems like I'm having a problem in my JS understanding. What's with the downvote?

Comment: So I liked this answer better than the other one. I personally think it a better approach since we reuse code and it's just seems semantically better. The creation of the new object is decoupled from it's structure (which is not the case in the other approach)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a  new item everytime you emit from child.

Like so:

```
  methods: {
    createItem() {
      let newItem = {
        id: this.count + 1
      };
      this.count = this.count + 1;
      this.$emit("setItem", newItem);
    }
```

Working implementation atttached.

[image: Edit affectionate-field-92z1z]

Comment: `id: this.count + 1` that will make case when `<li id="0">` it begins with counter value `1` instead of same as `id`. Just a note.

Comment: This is not eslint compatible.

Comment: @handy Since you had mentioned in OP that this is just a minimal reproduction.
I did not pay much attention to the semantics. 
Main point is that you were emitting same object everytime, but you need to emit a new item (object) on every click. 
Same is demostrated in the example given in the answer.